# How to print all permutation using backtracking?

Tags: c++, backtracking

This code prints all the permutation of N-1 items. But I could not understand one thing:
when n=N, it is returning where it is called and make flag[n-1] = false. Thus, i = N-1 and breaks the loop. But how is the rest of the permutation printing or returning when n=N-2 to 0?

```
void perm(int n) {
    if (n == N) {
        for (int i = 0; i < N ; i++) {
            cout<<a[i]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (flag[i]) continue;
        a[n] = i;
        flag[i] = true;
        cout<<i<<endl;
        perm(n + 1);
        cout<<i<<endl;
        flag[i] = false;

    }
}
```

Comment: this is a good opportunity to use a debugger

Comment: Can you explain what is `N`, `flag` and `a` is in your code?

Comment: `N` is the permutation length, `flag` is whether a given number was already used and `a` the selected number at given positions.

Comment: Your question is _"How to print all permutation using backtracking?"_ In the question is a code that _"prints all the permutation of N-1 items."_ What is your actual question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to consider that function calls ended up nested.

Each indentation below shows a nested call:

```
main()
    entering perm(0)
        entering perm(1)
            i = 0
            entering perm(2)
                let's say N is 2, this will print and return

        now perm(1) continues
            i becomes 1
            entering perm(2)
...
```

Since `return` only returns from the current function call, not all function calls, the permutations continue printing.

In order to gain familiarity with this, try this:

```
void perm(int n) {
std::cout << "Entering perm " << n << std::endl;
if (n == N) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N ; i++) {
        cout<<a[i]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
    std::cout << "Exiting perm " << n << std::endl;
    return;
}
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    if (flag[i]) continue;
    a[n] = i;
    flag[i] = true;
    cout<<i<<endl;
    std::cout << "about to call perm" << std::endl;
    perm(n + 1);
    std::cout << "finished call to perm" << std::endl;
    cout<<i<<endl;
    flag[i] = false;

}
    std::cout << "Exiting perm " << n << " (2)"<< std::endl;
}
```

Comment: when calling perm(2) ,i=1 , it returns and makes flag[1] = false. Thus, it breaks the loop, and there is no other return keyword. But how the perm(1) continues? After breaking the loop, does it enter in perm(1) by itself? Am I missing this?

Comment: Yeah, try it in a debugger. It's seem you're not familiar yet with nested function call. Remember that if `perm` calls itself, it will continue where it was before when it returns. There will also be multiple values for `i`, one at each nesting level